# What's the difference between Critical updates and Salesforce Release which take place thrice in a year?

Tags: community

I want to know about Salesforce Critical Updates and Salesforce Releases are they connected to each other or not? What are the major differences between them?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce periodically releases **critical updates** that improve the performance, logic, and usability of Salesforce, but which can affect your existing customizations. Salesforce lists them in Setup menu >"Critical Updates"

Each update can be manually activated or deactivated several times to evaluate its impact on the organization and modify the affected customizations accordingly. If the manual activation or deactivation is not done in a particular time frame, Salesforce auto activates the update permanently.

Whereas,
**Salesforce Release** upgrades are automatic on specific dates that are published up to a year in advance on the Salesforce Trust website. The first set of upgrades happens on sandbox instances 4-6 weeks before a release goes into production.These releases happen three times a year (Winter, Spring, Summer) that include many new features.We cannot activate them as needed like the critical updates.

Salesforce Release notes usually mention the critical updates that are coming up in the current release and also if there are any changes in the critical update auto-activation dates

Example: [https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_cruc.htm#:~:text=This%20critical%20update%20is%20postponed,within%20a%20top%2Dlevel%20component](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_cruc.htm#:%7E:text=This%20critical%20update%20is%20postponed,within%20a%20top%2Dlevel%20component).

References:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cruc_overview.htm&type=5
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sf_releases/sf_releases_start

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was helpful.